# Vectorize 'for' loops that call other functions

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, vectorization

I have the following code snippet in matlab with two 'for' loops:
'I' is a binary image that has been preallocated.

[image]

```
 ...
    [x,y] = find(bwmorph(I,'endpoints'));
    n=numel(x);
    m=numel(x)-1;
    n=m+1;
    r=i+1;
    for i= 1:m
        for j = r:n
            I=linept(I, x(i), y(i), x(j), y(j));
        end;
    end;
    ...
```

The linept function is given below.Its from the Matlab File Exchange:

```
function result=linept(matrix, X1, Y1, X2, Y2)
result = matrix;
a=max(1, X1);b=sign(X2 - X1);c=max(1, X2);
for x=a:b:c
    y = round(f(x, X1, Y1, X2, Y2));
    if y > 0
        result(x, y) = 1;
    end
end
d=max(1, Y1);e=sign(Y2 - Y1);g=max(1, Y2);
for y=d:e:g
    x = round(f2(y, X1, Y1, X2, Y2));
    if x > 0
        result(x, y) = 1;
    end
end

function y=f(x, X1, Y1, X2, Y2)
a = (Y2 - Y1)/(X2 - X1);
b = Y1 - X1 * a;
y = a * x + b;

function x=f2(y, X1, Y1, X2, Y2)
if X1==X2
    x = X1;
else
    a = (Y2 - Y1)/(X2 - X1);
    b = Y1 - X1 * a;
    x = (y - b)/a;
end
```

Due to the many 'for' loops and function calls, this code is running very slowly.It runs fast for a simple image with few end points, but it takes a lot of time when the number of edges is more.It is slightly faster if the size of the image is reduced.I tried to vectorise it and have preallocated some variables, but there isn't much improvement.Can anyone help me regarding how to vectorise codes that call functions in loops.Thank you

Comment: Could you share `func2` and `func3` function codes as well? Also, what are `m` in `n=m+1;` and `i` in `r=i+1;` at the start? SImilarly those `a,b,c`..could you add what do they signify?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question now

Comment: `a,b,c,d,e,g` in `func`?

Comment: I am sorry, the editing is taking time.This is actually connected to my previous questions.I will finish editing it soon

Comment: You could try to use `parfor` loops for different images to improve the running time. It will distribute the work to different cores on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

This was one great problem!!

**Brief discussion and solution codes**

Well, listed next is a vectorized approach that heavily uses **[`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** at various places to take care of connecting all points with all other points by `expansions` which is basically how `bsxfun` operates . The code in it uses a sample input data for demo purposes. Take a look -

```
%// Create demo input data
img = false(20);
img(2,5:15) = 1;
img(12,5:15) = 1;
figure,imagesc(img), colormap gray, title('Starting Binary image')

%// Find endpoints
[X,Y] = find(bwmorph(img,'endpoints'));

%// Make a new binary image with only endpoints in it
I = false(size(img));
I(sub2ind(size(I),X,Y)) = 1;
figure,imagesc(I), colormap gray, title('Endpoints detected')

%-------- Vectorized code starts here ...
[nrows,ncols] = size(I);  %// Parameters
npts = numel(X);

twopts = nchoosek(1:npts,2);
slopes = (Y(twopts(:,1)) - Y(twopts(:,2)))./(X(twopts(:,1)) - X(twopts(:,2)));

%// Find the connecting indices with X-Y as they are, to work with 
%// slopes within [-1 1]
stage1 = abs(slopes)<=1;
[colID,rowID] = connecting_idx(X,Y,twopts(stage1,:),slopes(stage1));
valid = colID>0 & rowID>0 & colID<=ncols & rowID<=nrows;
I((colID(valid)-1)*nrows + rowID(valid))=1;

%// Find the connecting indices with X-Y interchanged, to work with 
%// slopes outside [-1 1]
[rowID,colID] = connecting_idx(Y,X,twopts(~stage1,:),1./slopes(~stage1));
valid = colID>0 & rowID>0 & colID<=ncols & rowID<=nrows;
I((colID(valid)-1)*nrows + rowID(valid))=1;
figure,imagesc(I),colormap gray,title('Final output : Endpoints connected')
```

Associated function code (most important part of codebase) -

```
function [y_all,x_all] = connecting_idx(X,Y,twopts,slopes)

%// Find XY indices that connects the X, Y anchor points given the two points
%// combinations and the corresponding slopes

X_twopts = reshape(X(twopts),size(twopts));
Y_twopts = reshape(Y(twopts),size(twopts));

[sortedX_pairs1,sorted_idx1] = sort(X_twopts,2);
X_starts1 = sortedX_pairs1(:,1);
Y_pairs = Y_twopts;
Y_starts = Y_pairs(sorted_idx1==1);
offsets = Y_starts - slopes.*X_starts1;
max_X_len = max(diff(sortedX_pairs1,[],2));

x_all = bsxfun(@plus,X_starts1,[0:max_X_len]);
x_lens = diff(sortedX_pairs1,[],2);
mask = bsxfun(@gt,x_lens+1,0:max_X_len);
y_all = round(bsxfun(@plus,bsxfun(@times,x_all,slopes),offsets));

y_all = y_all(mask);
x_all = x_all(mask);

return;
```

**Debug images after code run -**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what you have done in this part in more detail:`stage1 = abs(slopes)<=1;
[colID,rowID] = connecting_idx(X,Y,twopts(stage1,:),slopes(stage1));
valid = colID>0 & rowID>0 & colID<=ncols & rowID<=nrows;
I((colID(valid)-1)*nrows + rowID(valid))=1;`

Comment: @Matt Well `slopes` is an array that stores the slopes for all points in pairs. With `stage1` I am selecting the pairs that have slopes within [-1 1] and then finding the connecting between those pairs. In the next step, if you see, I am using `~stage1` to select the rest of the pairs and find their connecting indices. Thus, after getting connecting indices from both steps we set those in the input matrix as ones.

Comment: Thanks for explaining :) I got the endpoints for an image from your code as shown here:http://imgur.com/3ARixR6,DoYZrhl#1.But when the lines were connected the output was:http://imgur.com/3ARixR6,DoYZrhl#0.Could you check if that is the case for you too?

Comment: @Matt Yeah I just noticed that issue with some other images too, think I need sometime to debug on what's going inside the codes, once more!

Comment: I'll go through the code once again and try to understand it perfectly!

Comment: Could you please tell me the error in the code if you have debugged it? I have tried to find it but it took me a lot of time to understand the vectorised code and I couldn't locate the error